# Optimize a JS query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm working on a project in Java/HTML5 and I made a script in JS to get a better display. (I just started to learn JS/jQuery)

So my HTML code is like this :

```
...
<section id="prod">
<h2>PROD</h2>
         <article class="service">
              <h3>A title</h3>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  ...
          </article>
         <article class="service">
              <h3>A title</h3>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  ...
          </article>
          ...
</section>
<section id="otherprod">
<h2>OTHERPROD</h2>
         <article class="service">
              <h3>A title</h3>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  ...
          </article>
         <article class="service">
              <h3>A title</h3>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  <p> p element </p>
                  ...
          </article>
          ...
</section>
```

I need to get all the "prod section", meaning, articles from section which has the id="prod".
So to do that, I did the query :

```
var elements = document.getElementById('prod').getElementsByTagName(
        'article');
```

which allows me to get the sections objects into elements.
The problem is that it seems it doesn't work well since I get some elements from "otherprod" into my elements objects.

Is it possible to get a jQuery query which gives me a list of objects with the  node I'm asking for, the same way I currently have ? Because next things I do is

```
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    current = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('p').length;
    ...
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You can only have __one__ section with an ID called `prod`.

Comment: I do only have one section with an ID called prod

Comment: you mean contains prod?

Comment: Do you have used any jQuery yet?

Comment: You said 'sections with the id="prod"' - I assumed you had more than one.

Comment: No jQuery yet, i was affraid to not being able to use my following code

Comment: Wait, you dont want JQuery answers???

Comment: @JFit, i'm not against jquery, just want to use the results the way i currently do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is just about selectors right? Here is a good link on selectors in JQuery,
https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/154_cheatsheet/jquery12_colorcharge.png

Also here is your code in a jsfiddle with selectors written as you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/7d5U2/

```
//all sections with id prod
$('section#prod').css('background-color','red');
//All articles within section#prod 
$('section#prod article').css('background-color','blue');
```

All jquery selectors return an array of elements. even if only one. you can then apply whatever you want to the returned elements. although some things like .val() will only act on first element in the returned array.

Comment: Is it possible to put the results into a JS variable ?

Comment: what result you need to put on variable ?

Comment: yes do `var x = $('section#prod');` and you'll get an array of the objects returned. to do javascript things to it you'll have to get the array element itself.. `var x = $('section#prod')[0];`

Answer (score 0):

That work ?

```
// Loop all section, or replace by #prod for just one section
$('section').each(function(){
   var $section = $(this); // Current section

   // Loop all acticle on this section
   $('article', $section).each(function(){
       var $artcile = $(this); // Current Article

       // Display count p on this $article
       console.log( $('p', $article).length );
   });

});

// Select all sections
$('section') ....

// Select only one
$('#prod') ....

// Select all articles
$('section article') ....

// Select articles from one section 
$('#prod article') ....

// Select all p 
$('section article p') ....
// Or simply
$('p') ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#prod>article, #otherprod>article').each(function(){
  var actualArticleValue = $(this).val();
 //foo bar
 });
```

this can be an each function that allow you to iterate around all article from prod and otherprod.